# ASP.NET MVC Global Error Handling with ELMAH - best practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling, elmah

I really would like to integrate ELMAH into my MVC4 application but I'm having a few issues:

- if elmah redirects all errors to a specific error page, do I only need to return success (eg for update, delete, ...) to the user?
- if elmah catches all errors do i need to handle errors (e.g. use `try catch`blocks) in my code at all?
- is there a best practise example somewhere how to use ELMAH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Elmah does do any redirects, so you have handle error pages yourself in web.config (hot ot do this you can look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2012/01/15/custom-error-pages-and-404-page-not-found-error-web-config-setup.aspx))

2) You should. Elmah is for logging unhandled exceptions. You can log handled exceptions like this:

```
try
{
    .....
}
catch(Exception ex) 
{
     Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex); 
}
```

3) There is a nice article is on Scott Hanselman blog: ELMAH: [Error Logging Modules and Handlers for ASP.NET (and MVC too!)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)

Comment: Also consider using the excellent Elmah.MVC project - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC for painless integration of Elmah with MVC.